# How can I change the string to the Thread class in ruby on rails

Tags: multithreading, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activejob, pthread-join, ruby-thread

Let's understand the scenario, I have to call a third party API in one of the API calls to my server **(let say A)** from the mobile app. That third party API takes almost 12-15 seconds to execute. However, in the next consecutive API call to my server **(let say B)**, I need to have the response of that third party API before start processing.

Here, It's important for me to call that third party API in a new thread in the first API call to my server i.e. ***A***. So that I can efficiently use the processing time for my second API i.e. ***B*** as the mobile user has to give certain inputs b/w these two API's ***A & B***.

The solution I have in my mind is that I will hit the third party API in the new thread, will save the thread reference in a variable and pass it in the response of my first API call like

`@th_ref = Thread.new do`

`// serive for third party api`

`end`

`json.thread_ref  @th_ref`

In the next API call i.e. ***B***, I will get this reference in a body and then I will join my main thread with the previous thread so that ***B*** does not start work until I get the third party API response.

But with the above solution, I get the thread_ref in **String class** in the second API's body like

> "#<Thread:0x00007fc84e316e38@(pry):157 run>"

and I have to change it back to **Thread class** so that I can use functions like `thread_ref.join` or `thread_ref.alive?`

Kindly suggest how can I achieve this conversion and am I using the right approach for my problem?

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: @CarlV. Not exactly, but I came up with a **"solution"** to solve the urgent issue at that time. Major steps were

Comment: **1**- I passed the thread reference (that called the 3rd party API ) to the API. 
**2**- Then after next 2-3 APIs or whenever it's needed, mobile app sends me back that thread_reference in the request body.
**3**- From there, I manipulated the thread_reference status from "run" to "sleep".
**4**- Then I searched for this thead in the list thead_list using `prev_thread = Thread.list.select {|thread| thread if thread.to_s == thread_ref_from_api}`
**5**- From there, I bind the main thread with the previous thread, that called the 3rd API before, to see if its execution is completed or not.

Comment: I hope you could find a better solution than this :)